# Qt Creator running CMake with different configuration

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm trying to build a CMakeLists project using Qt Creator 4.8.1. The problem is, I need to run CMake inside a different nativesysroot. 
I tried to create a bash script that runs CMake inside the other environment and added it to my kit. As follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop/Workspace/my_proj/build &&\ 
~/Desktop/Workspace/my_proj/sdk-x86_64/opt/nativesysroot/usr/bin/sysroot\
~/Desktop/Workspace/my_proj/sdk-vmwx86-x86_64/opt/nativesysroot/usr/bin/cmake "$@"
```

Such that, sysroot is an executable that changes the current nativesysroot.
The problem is this does not work because Qt Creator is trying to run CMake using the following configuration:

> Running "/home/***/Desktop/Workspace/my_proj/script.sh -E server --pipe=/tmp/cmake-.ewYqvn/socket --experimental" in /tmp/QtCreator-kruzfX/qtc-cmake-YOZsCIQx.

This of course causes CMake server connection lost. I tried the look around how to disable the CMake running in server mode but I did not find anything in Qt Creator.

My question is, how to disable CMake in server mode? Or, how to instruct Qt Creator to run my script without adding any flags or options?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not teach CMake to respect a certain sysroot so that you don't have to hack it in externally? This sounds like you're trying to bypass the system of e.g. CMake Toolchain files (which seem to be a much better option for you). To be able to answer this, we need to know _exactly_ what your `sysroot` binary actually does.

Comment: It changes to system roots to be inside the other environment. For example, when i run it inside the terminal, it changes the current user and the system roots. If I cd to /, it will navigate to the root directory of the newer system roots.

Comment: So it sets up a chroot? That's unfortunate. I guess the only way is to start Qt Creator from inside that chroot.

Comment: Yes it does change the root. However, it works in my terminal if I run the CMake using the script I wrote for Qt Creator, even inside my host root.
The problem is coming from the flags `-E server --pipe=/tmp/cmake-.cQJDwS/socket --experimental` I tried to hard to disable them and I could not find a way to do it. It once worked but did not remember how. If I can remove these flags it should be fine.

Comment: Qt Creator automatically uses server mode for CMake >= 3.7. So perhaps using an older CMake version is an option for you?

Comment: I'm stuck with the CMake provided by the sdk. However, how even Qt Creator detected the version of CMake, given that I'm giving it a bash script in the CMake path in my Kit?

Comment: probably by invoking your wrapper with --version or some other way. You are passing all arguments through to the actual CMake command...

Comment: You are right. It happens only when Qt Creator detects the CMake version. It happens after I add the CMake to my kit then restarts Qt.
Where does Qt cache the information about kits?